# Generating subsets of n-element set; function doesn't return anything

Tags: python, set, combinations, ipython, subset

```
def nast(L):
    i=len(L)-1
    while L != [1 for i in range(len(L))]:
        if L[i]==0:
            L[i]=1
            break
        i=i-1
    for j in range(i+1,len(L)):
        L[j]=0
    return L

def extr(dss,bb):
    for i in list(dss.keys()):
        if bb[i]==0:
            dss.pop(i)
    w=list(dss.values())
    return w

def GenSet(ss):
    L1=[0 for i in range(len(ss))]
    w=[()]
    while L1 != [1 for i in range(len(ss))]:
        dss=dict(zip([i for i in range(len(ss))],list(ss)))
        tL1=tuple(nast(L1))
        temp=extr(dss,tL1)
        temp1=tuple(temp)
        w.append(temp1)
    ww= [set(x) for x in w]
    return ww, len(ww)
```

I want this code to generate subsets of n-element set. Unfortunately, **GenSet()** does not return neither value, neither error; it crashes Ipython's shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pitfall:

```
i=len(L)-1
while L != [1 for i in range(len(L))]:
```

The `i` that appears in the list comprehension will override the other one.

Comment: This depends on the python version. It will on python < 3. On python3 the outside `i` is preserved since they live in different scopes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; would it be an issue, if you'd help and share a solution of this problem? Could you tell me what does '1' before 'for'  mean? (I didn't write this code, but I do need to compile it)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your code, but have you considered using itertools instead?

The following snippet will generate all subsets of size n :

```
import itertools
def subsets(bigset,n):
    return itertools.combinations(bigset, n)
```

Then you can simply join the results together.

Comment: The function `subsets` is *completely* futile. You are only adding overhead on a plain call to `itertools.combinations`. If you want to give an other name for clarity simply do `subsets = itertools.combinations` to achieve the same affect of your code but without increased overhead.

Comment: For any live usage, you're perfectly right. This is a demonstrative example.